# Verifying .asc file for TorBrowser-linux64-4.0.4_en-US.tar.xz

Tags: verification

I executed this part of the instructions from the Tor website:

> The next step is to use GnuPG to import the key that signed your package. The Tor Browser team signs the Tor Browsers. Import its key (0x4E2C6E8793298290) by starting the terminal (under "Applications" in Mac OS X) and typing:
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver x-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290
> ```
>
> After importing the key, you can verify that the fingerprint is correct:
>
> ```
> gpg --fingerprint 0x4E2C6E8793298290
> ```
>
> You should see:
>
> ```
> pub   4096R/93298290 2014-12-15
>       Key fingerprint = EF6E 286D DA85 EA2A 4BA7  DE68 4E2C 6E87 9329 8290
> uid                  Tor Browser Developers (signing key) 
> sub   4096R/F65C2036 2014-12-15
> sub   4096R/D40814E0 2014-12-15
> sub   4096R/589839A3 2014-12-15
> ```
>
> To verify the signature of the package you downloaded, you will need to download the ".asc" file as well. Assuming you downloaded the package and its signature to your Desktop, run:

**I execute :**

```
gpg --verify ~/Desktop/tor-browser-linux64-4.0.4_en-US.tar.xz{.asc*,}
```

**But I get this error:**

```
gpg: can't open `/home/user/Desktop/tor-browser-linux64-4.0.4_en-US.tar.xz.asc*'
gpg: verify signatures failed: file open error
```

**Conclusion:**

Just to clarify I have both the tar.xz and the tar.xz.asc file in my Downloads folder.  Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either move the files to your Desktop and re-run the commands, or change the word "Desktop" to "Download" in the command you executed, like this:

```
gpg --verify ~/Desktop/tor-browser-linux64-4.0.4_en-US.tar.xz{.asc*,}
```